# Selecting informations from multiples with left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I think all i need a little hint for completing this query built with a left outer join.

This is a basic example from a my query which list informations from different tables:

```
select t.Transaction_ID, t.Date_Transaction
from  Transactions t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Trans_Payments on Trans_Payments.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
```

this query returns :

```
trans_id   trans_date
1             20/10/2010
1             20/10/2011
2             20/10/2012 
3             20/10/2014
4             20/2/2015
5             18/10/2010
```

That's a good start since this query list all the transactions even the ones with no payment_mode ( because before i was using a simple join in where for listing transactions and all i get is transactions with a payment mode)

Ok, now when i try to add another join:

```
select *
from  Transactions t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Trans_Payments on Trans_Payments.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments on Trans_Payments.Payment_ID = Payments.Payment_ID
```

i get :

[image: query_result]

How can I get rid of transaction_id and duplicated payment_id in this query result?

Answer (score 0):

Add the field names you want into your select clause e.g:

```
SELECT t.Transaction_ID, TransPayments.Payment_ID, Amount etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Asterisk. Define the columns that you want.